# Column header for different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have many rows having data in sheet 2 and I want the column name of the max of a row (i.e. from column name of B2 to AH2 inside if loop).

```
Sub shanaya()
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    z = 35
    For i = 11 To 28
        For j = 2 To 19
            If Sheet8.Cells(j, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) Then
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 10) = Sheet8.Cells(j, z)
                Max [(Sheet8.Cells(J,2)): (Sheet8.Cells(j,z))]
                Sheet1.Cells(i,13) = column header of max function
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two key lines you need are along the lines of:

```
MaxVal = application.max(sheet8.range(sheet8.cells(j,2),sheet8.cells(j,z)))
sheet1.cells(i,13) = sheet8.cells(1,application.match(MaxVal,sheet8.rows(j)))
```

The first line finds the maximum value in the row. The second line returns the column header (presumably in row 1 as you're searching from row 2).